# Jest mock exports.name does not work properly

Tags: mocking, jestjs

I have the following js code

```js
exports.setupUserAccounts = config => {
  //Implementation
};
```

This is located in the 'shared/user' folder.  Now in the test file I'm trying to mock this method using jest (I'm not using DI)

I'm writing the following code to that effect

```
jest.mock('shared/user')
```

Now when I run the code I get the following error

> **setupUserAccounts** is not a method

I also try the following

```js
jest.mock('shared/user', () => ({
  setupUserAccounts: jest.fn()
}));
```

Now when I run the test, the function is not mocked at all.  Just to add to this, my source is TypeScript code and I'm running `ts-jest`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an unit test working example:

`index.ts`:

```js
const { setupUserAccounts } = require('./shared/user');

export function main() {
  return setupUserAccounts();
}
```

`shared/user/index.ts`:

```js
exports.setupUserAccounts = config => {
  console.log('setupUserAccounts');
};
```

`index.spec.ts`

```js
const { main } = require('./');
const { setupUserAccounts } = require('./shared/user');

jest.mock('./shared/user', () => {
  return {
    setupUserAccounts: jest.fn()
  };
});

test('should mock setupUserAccounts correctly', () => {
  expect(jest.isMockFunction(setupUserAccounts)).toBeTruthy();
  (setupUserAccounts as jest.MockedFunction<typeof setupUserAccounts>).mockReturnValueOnce('fake data');
  const actualValue = main();
  expect(actualValue).toBe('fake data');
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/56961691/index.spec.ts
  ✓ should mock setupUserAccounts correctly (4ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.885s, estimated 8s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/56961691